# Rails 3 - Ajax helpers

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to submit a form remotely.

```
<% form_for @awareness_item, :remote => 'true', :url => admin_awareness_item_path(@awareness_item), :html => {:id => 'updteAwarenessItem'} do |f| %>
```

and have the below ajax callbacks configured to the form,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#updteAwarenessItem").unbind();
$("#updteAwarenessItem")
.bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
   console.log('...POSTING....');
})
.bind("ajax:loading", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
 console.log('...LOADING....');
});
```

});

The problem is, that though I have bound the ajax:loading callback with the form, it never gets called. The onlything that ever gets called is ajax:success. Kindly let me know how can I bind ajax:loading and ajax:complete to the form. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Some callbacks have been renamed (see the [pull request](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/pull/56)).

`ajax:loading` is now `ajax:beforeSend`, because it's been named beforeSend in jQuery, to avoid confusion.